# Fullscreen feature for custom video player broke after updating to Chrome Version 69, what are the changes which can cause this?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have been working on making a custom video player, I had developed a fullscreen mode where the player scales to fit the screen in full-screen mode. But, this feature broke when Chrome's new update came out. It is still working on Chrome Version 65. Following is the link to the fiddle where I have tried to replicate the error.

https://jsfiddle.net/dhwanilshah/0j31px2v/20/

The player div does not scale as the container scales which used to happen earlier.

```
// Scale to fit the screen, this scales the parent but not the children
function callFullScreen () {
  var el = document.getElementById('main-video-container')
  // Scaling parameters are calculated based on the screen sizes of the device to best fit the screen
  el.style.transform = 'scale(1.5, 1.5)'
  // Supports most browsers and their versions.
  const requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullscreen
  if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(el)
  }
}
```

I have tested this feature and the same code works on Chrome Version 65 and not on Chrome Version 69.

Any suggestions are welcome and are appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, not on jsFiddle (or in addition to jsFiddle). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Go learn how to use browser dev tools, using those it is quite easy to figure out where this comes from. Go into fullscreen mode, inspect the element - and you will see that `transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);` is crossed out in the Styles panel. Look further down to see what styles are applied, and you find that there is a rule from the browser stylesheet, with the selector `:not(:root):-webkit-full-screen` that explicitly sets `transform: none !important;` (and values for a lot of other properties with !important, too.)

Comment: The easiest workaround here would be that you do not apply the transformation to the element that you are “making” full-screen, but to a child element inside of it. Then the selector `:not(:root):-webkit-full-screen` will not match any more.

Comment: @misorude Yes, I went around and found out that the div which is being put into full-screen does not get the transform applied to it. So, I put the parent division of the division which I was putting till date and then scaled it and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the information about the `:not(:root):-webkit-full-screen` selector. It helped me understand the problem much better.

Comment: @misorude Add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using browser dev tools, it is quite easy to figure out where this comes from. Go into fullscreen mode, inspect the element - and you will see that `transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);` is crossed out in the Styles panel.

Look further down to see what styles are applied, and you find that there is a rule from the browser stylesheet, with the selector `:not(:root):-webkit-full-screen` that explicitly sets `transform: none !important;` (and values for a lot of other properties with !important, too.)

The easiest workaround here would be that you do not apply the transformation to the element that you are “making” full-screen, but to a child element inside of it. Then the selector `:not(:root):-webkit-full-screen` will not match any more.